# constrain dimension based on "other" dimension

Tags: android, view, aspect-ratio

I want to create a view such that one of the dimensions is based on a weight.  However, I want that view to have a particular aspect ratio.  In this case, i want it to be square.

So I wind up having something like this:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/MyPicture"
    android:layout_width="???"
    android:layout_height="0"
    android:layout_weight="2"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"
    android:src="@drawable/mypicture"/>
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You would have to do that in Java code. There is no way in XML to specify one dimension is dependent upon another dimension.